# Origin of the original bright light and matter

Tags: universe

Do any theories exist as to where this bright light and matter came from that expanded to form our Universe ?

Comment: What do you mean by "original bright light"?

Comment: I think they mean the mass/energy came from in the big-bang.

Comment: Yes, I don't know exactly what to call it but whatever it was that expanded or exploded, referred to as "the big bang" to create the Universe that we live in today . What created this ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that what you want to know is "where did everything come from?" As for the light and the matter itself, we have some pretty good theories: **Matter** consists of many different particles, each of which were created from energy at different epoch during the first few moments of the Big Bang (BB). For instance, leptons were created from 1 to 10 seconds after BB, hadrons from 10<sup>-6</sup> to 1 seconds after BB, and quarks even earlier. **Light** was created when the different particles annihilated with their corresponding antiparticles.

As to how the original energy — from which light and matter came — was created in the first place, there definitely is no well-grounded theory here, but either we must accept that

1. the Universe came into existence out of nothing, or else
2. there was something before that created the Universe, in which case we either

   1. just push the question further back, or
   2. must accept that whatever was there before has been there for eternity.

Option 2.2 is boring because I don't think there's any way of testing this theory, so option 1 or 2.1 seem most appealing, especially option 1, since time itself is thought to have been created along with space (though I think there are models where this is not necessarily the case).

Creating something out of nothing seems magical, but in fact **it happens all the time**. A vacuum is the lowest state of energy, but as a consequence of Heisenberg's uncertainty principle, in a finite time, the lowest state of energy cannot be zero, since ΔE Δt ≳ ℏ. This results in so-called quantum fluctuations. Usually, the energy popping up out of nowhere annihilates immediately, but there are ways of making it survive (e.g. on the border of a black hole). In a similar way, universes can be thought to pop up out of nowhere. Such a universe could annihilate immediately, but if inflated fast enough to a large enough size, it could grow to macroscopic size before it has time to annihilate.

If you want to read further, Wikipedia has some nice articles on the [timeline of Big Bang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_the_universe) and [cosmogony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmogony) (the theory of stuff coming into being)

Comment: Even though the question was put on "hold", as being hard to tell what it is that I am asking, you seem to have had no problem in knowing what my question is. It is very mind boggling that the solid matter that now exists in the Universe came about out of "nothing" but this seems like the most acceptable theory. If the matter that is now in the Universe came out of something then the question will always remain as to where that something came from . So out of nothing came everything but we will never be able to understand how this could happen ?

Comment: I agree that it is mind boggling, and that probably we won't understand this for many generations to come. But very clever people are working hard to understand this, as it is one of, if not _the_, most fundamental questions you are asking, and I would not dare to claim that mankind will never be able to understand how this could happen. :)